# Match multiple lines and print certain groups only

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a regexp that lists all alsa devices with pvolume capability.
Basically:

```
amixer | perl -0pe "s/Simple mixer control '(.*)',(.*)\n  Capabilities: .*pvolume.*\n(  .*\n)*(  (.*): Playback .*\[([0-9]+)%\].*\[(on|off)\]\n)/\2 - \1 (Vol. \6) (\7)\n/g"
```

But this will print groups that it can't match.

I tried it with "-0ne" and "print if s/..." but it's still the same.

How can I make it so it prints only those that I want?

Amixer output:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 81 [93%] [-4.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 71 [82%] [-12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 71 [82%] [-12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Bass Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958 Default PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 26 [84%] [22.50dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 26 [84%] [22.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
  Capabilities: cvolume
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 120
  Front Left: Capture 87 [72%] [13.50dB]
  Front Right: Capture 87 [72%] [13.50dB]
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 23 [74%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 23 [74%] [0.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
```

Output of my command (using the flag -n with "print if" doesn't change the output)

```
0 - Master (Vol. 93) (on)
0 - Headphone (Vol. 100) (on)
0 - Speaker (Vol. 82) (on)
Simple mixer control 'Bass Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
0 - Mic (Vol. 100) (off)
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958 Default PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 26 [84%] [22.50dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 26 [84%] [22.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
  Capabilities: cvolume
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 120
  Front Left: Capture 87 [72%] [13.50dB]
  Front Right: Capture 87 [72%] [13.50dB]
0 - Internal Mic (Vol. 74) (off)
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
```

Desired output:

```
0 - Master (Vol. 93) (on)
0 - Headphone (Vol. 100) (on)
0 - Speaker (Vol. 82) (on)
0 - Mic (Vol. 100) (off)
0 - Internal Mic (Vol. 74) (off)
```

Comment: Written as it is, it is quite difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Could you please provide some sample inputs, outputs and what your current (incorrect) outputs are?

Comment: This looks like a record that spans several lines. The problem is that the voids are being filled with `.*` which is ok if there is no /s modifier, otherwise its a backtracking nightmare in waiting.

Comment: @Jerry My correct outputs are those that print only the devices that meet the criteria. I thought using amixer output would mean everyone could copy/paste it to their terminals to see what was wrong with it. I will put up an example since that hasn't been the case.

Comment: @sln Yes but that is not one of my concerns now, is it

Comment: Okay, I'm not entirely familiar with perl, but I made [this up](http://regex101.com/r/nZ7aO5) through some edits of your current regex.

Comment: The first problem is trying to gleen your intent from your regex, which is unclear. The second is its not clear how you got the 'qualified' record filter output (desired output). Its really very simple to do, but the intent is the barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-n` flag instead of `-p`; the latter automatically prints lines. And *then* add the print statement: e.g.:

```
$ cat .zshrc | perl -n -e "print if s/down/hello/g"
```

Results in:

```
# Up and hello arrows search history matching input so far {{{
autoload hello-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N hello-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[B" hello-line-or-beginning-search
```

Comment: I have said this approach produces the same output. I put up an example output to make it more clear.

Comment: Um, no it doesn't. It produces no output at all[1]. Are you sure you're using *just* the "-ne" flag, and have removed the "p" flag? [1] The reason it doesn't produce any output is because you also need to use "-0777" for multiline slurping, and possibly "/mg" instead of "/g" for multiline mode.

Comment: How about just grepping again? E.g.: `amixer | perl -0777 -i -ne "(s/Simple mixer control '(.*)',(.*)\n  Capabilities: .*pvolume.*\n(  .*\n)*(  (.*): Playback .*\[([0-9]+)%\].*\[(on|off)\]\n)/\2 - \1 (Vol. \6) (\7)\n/g and print)" | grep "^\d"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. Use the /mg option's

```
 # /^Simple[ ]mixer[ ]control.*'([^']*)',(\d+).*\n[ ]{2}Capabilities:.+pvolume.*\n[ ]{2}Playback.*\n(?:[ ]{2}.*\n)*?[ ]{2}.*\[(\d+)%\].*\[(on|off)\]/

 ^ Simple [ ] mixer [ ] control .* 
 '
 ( [^']* )                     # (1)
 ',
 ( \d+ )                       # (2)
 .* \n 
 [ ]{2} Capabilities: .+ pvolume .* \n 
 [ ]{2} Playback .* \n 
 (?: [ ]{2} .* \n )*?
 [ ]{2} .* 
 \[
 ( \d+ )                       # (3)
 %\]
 .* 
 \[ 
 ( on | off )                  # (4)
 \]
```

Perl test case

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 $/ = undef;

 my $str = <DATA>;


 while ($str =~ /^Simple[ ]mixer[ ]control.*'([^']*)',(\d+).*\n[ ]{2}Capabilities:.+pvolume.*\n[ ]{2}Playback.*\n(?:[ ]{2}.*\n)*?[ ]{2}.*\[(\d+)%\].*\[(on|off)\]/mg)
 {
    print "$2 - $1 (Vol. $3) ($4)\n";
 }

  __DATA__

 Simple mixer control 'Master',0
   Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
   Playback channels: Mono
   Limits: Playback 0 - 87
   Mono: Playback 81 [93%] [-4.50dB] [on]
 Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
   Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
   Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Limits: Playback 0 - 87
   Mono:
   Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
   Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
 Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
   Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
   Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Limits: Playback 0 - 87
   Mono:
   Front Left: Playback 71 [82%] [-12.00dB] [on]
   Front Right: Playback 71 [82%] [-12.00dB] [on]
 Simple mixer control 'Bass Speaker',0
   Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
   Playback channels: Mono
   Mono: Playback [off]
 Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
   Capabilities: pvolume
   Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Limits: Playback 0 - 255
   Mono:
   Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
   Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
 Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
   Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
   Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Limits: Playback 0 - 31
   Mono:
   Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [off]
   Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [12.00dB] [off]
 Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
   Capabilities: volume
   Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Limits: 0 - 3
   Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
   Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
 Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
   Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
   Playback channels: Mono
   Mono: Playback [off]
 Simple mixer control 'IEC958 Default PCM',0
   Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
   Playback channels: Mono
   Mono: Playback [on]
 Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
   Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
   Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Limits: Capture 0 - 31
   Front Left: Capture 26 [84%] [22.50dB] [on]
   Front Right: Capture 26 [84%] [22.50dB] [on]
 Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
   Capabilities: enum
   Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
   Item0: 'Disabled'
 Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
   Capabilities: cvolume
   Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Limits: Capture 0 - 120
   Front Left: Capture 87 [72%] [13.50dB]
   Front Right: Capture 87 [72%] [13.50dB]
 Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic',0
   Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
   Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Limits: Playback 0 - 31
   Mono:
   Front Left: Playback 23 [74%] [0.00dB] [off]
   Front Right: Playback 23 [74%] [0.00dB] [off]
 Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
   Capabilities: volume
   Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
   Limits: 0 - 3
   Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
   Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
```

Output >>

```
 0 - Master (Vol. 93) (on)
 0 - Headphone (Vol. 100) (on)
 0 - Speaker (Vol. 82) (on)
 0 - Mic (Vol. 100) (off)
 0 - Internal Mic (Vol. 74) (off)
```